# Why so much leaf burn on my Viburnum opulus 'Roseum'?

Tags: leaves, shrubs, sunlight

I have a young Viburnum opulus 'Roseum' in my garden that is planted in a partially shaded area. It only receives about 4-5 hours of direct sunlight in the morning. The plant is against a fence that faces a north easterly direction. I moved it from the other side of the garden, which receives full sun, thinking that this would be more suitable for this plant after I noticed some shrivelling of the leaves.

Nevertheless, I've noticed quite a lot of leaf burn/scorch (see photos).[image][image] In many guides, it says the plant can be planted in full sun or partial shade. So I can't understand why I have this problem.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Where are you in the world and precisely when did you move the plant to its current position?

Comment: @Bamboo I am in London, Uk. I moved the plant early May.